# Search Images in Google and get JSON response

Tags: google-search, google-image-search

I am trying to search google images with keywords I used the following

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?searchType=image&key=my_custom_search_key&cx=my_custom_search_engine_key&q=love

but I got the following json

```
{

    "kind": "customsearch#search",
    "url": {

        "type": "application/json",
        "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&cref={cref?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"

    },
    "queries": {

        "request": [

            {
                "title": "Google Custom Search - love",
                "totalResults": "0",
                "searchTerms": "love",
                "count": ​10,
                "inputEncoding": "utf8",
                "outputEncoding": "utf8",
                "safe": "off",
                "cx": "my_custom_search_engine_key",
                "searchType": "image"
            }
        ]

    },
    "searchInformation": {
        "searchTime": ​0.054318,
        "formattedSearchTime": "0.05",
        "totalResults": "0",
        "formattedTotalResults": "0"
    }

}
```

Which does not give me the search result of images, I need to get the image's urls and the description in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I found love with your query but my key and cx. But earlier I have similar problem, and my problem was with https://cse.google.com/cse/setup/basic?cx={YOUR_CX}
I set "Image Search" to ON. Click "update" to save your changes.